# Remove punctuation standard input.

Tags: bash

I want the program can remove punctuation which read from the standard input
My code is:

```
echo $* | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

It can handle some simple situations but when I type input in terminal (like: whatever ad!":)

when the sentence within continuing several punctuation, the terminal will reflect the result: -bash: !": event not found

Can anyone give help?

Comment: you can also use sed instead of `tr` like `echo 'Whatever ad!":' | sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g''`

Comment: $* is the string parameter that I type it in terminal. The file to edit shell script named stripchars and commands and pipe are edited in this file, and I run it like ./stripchars abc abc can be instead of other strings. So i don't want string is to be edited inside the file. Do you have any other ideas to solve the problem if the string includes continuous punctuation and how to treat ! continue with another punctuation as normal char

Answer (score 4):

single quotes should be used to avoid expansion, e.g.

```
echo 'whatever ad!' | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

under a bash shell it prints out

```
whatever ad
```

and if you want to use a variable

```
BUFF='whatever ?_-!!!!ad!'; echo "$BUFF" | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

---

***EDIT 1***

this is a complete script following your request

```
#!/bin/sh
functionStripAndPrint()
{
  echo "$@" | tr -d '[:punct:]'
}

functionStripAndPrint "$@"
```

assuming that this script is stored in the `stripchars.sh` file, you can invoke it like so

```
./stripchars.sh 'das !adsa _sda ssad-'
```

and it will print

```
das adsa sda ssad
```

---

***EDIT 2***

you can work around the interpretation of some of the special characters with `set`, for example

```
set +H
```

deactivates [the `H` option](http://ss64.com/bash/set.html) which is linked to the `!` symbol, so now `!` is just an exclamation mark with no special meaning. You can then simplify your invocation a little bit

./stripchars.sh sdfsa!fdsaf?\'

as you can see the only problem at this point is the `'` that still needs to be escaped.

If you want to re-enable the `H` you do

```
set -H
```

`set` is handy to modify the behaviour of your shell, I don't know if it's worth in your case, the shell is good and handy for some basic stuff, but I don't know if this will fit your needs, you know better, take a look at `set` and see if it's enough.

Comment: $* is the string parameter that I type it in terminal. The file to edit shell script named stripchars and commands and pipe are edited in this file, and I run it like ./stripchars abc      abc can be instead of other strings. So i don't want string is to be edited inside the file. Do you have any other ideas to solve the problem if the string includes continuous punctuation and how to treat ! as normal char

Comment: @JAC see if the edit fits your needs .

Comment: thank you for your help. but did you try if the end of the string is !" or ?" , it also shows -bash: even not found, do you have any method can solve that problem

Comment: @JAC I'm under Ubuntu with a bash and it works with any character, I can't see any particular problem with it, how do you invoke it ? Please add more details .

Comment: can you do not use single quotes for the string, just type string without quotes, or do you know how to convert it to let the string i typed without quotes be quoted

Comment: @JAC if your invocation is `'sdfsa!fdsaf?''` your problem is the second `'`, because it needs to be escaped and if not, it will redefine your string closing it before the third `'`; this will also cause the third `'` to be read as a special character and this is what is triggering the message that you see. The invocation with `./stripchars.sh 'sdfsa!fdsaf?'` is totally fine, you can't use `'` like that because it's a string delimiter for the shell. If you need some advanced string manipulation features, and you find that the shell it's not enough, I'll suggest to switch to python 2.x .

Comment: @JAC I have added 1 more option, but `'` and `"` are builtin delimiters for the bash, I don't think you can work around those 2.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, `bash` uses `!` to get commands from the history of commands. When you type

```
echo Whatever ad!":
```

it tries to retrieve the command from its command history by using `!":`. Since it does not find any command using that, it prints the message

```
bash: !": event not found
```

You can pass those special characters to `bash` by (1) using single quote to let special characters be treated like normal characters, or (2) escaping the special characters.

```
echo 'Whatever ad!":'  | tr -d '[:punct:]' 
echo Whatever ad\!\":  | tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

Comment: text(Whatever ad!":) is an parameter that I typed in terminal, and the command to remove punctuation is edited in a file. I want to let the program can solve the situation when I type anything which include continuous punctuation like(!":") in terminal directly as standard input not to edit the text inside of the shell script file. I have an idea about to convert the parameter which is a string to normal characters, but I don't know how to convert.